# How to call class method from one php file in another using javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, class

i have a class like so

```
class TestClass() {
   public function TestFunction() {
        return "TESTING"
    }
}
```

I am importing the class in another php file like so

```
use \Path\To\TestClass


<script>
how to call it here ?
</script>
```

and here using js i want to call the method that exists in that class
how can i do it ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your JavaScript code runs in the browser (the client), while your php code runs on the server. Thus, you'll have to arrange to make an HTTP request on the client to do anything back on the server.

Comment: Make a HTTP request from JS to a PHP script which then calls the relevant function. You can't call PHP functions direct from JS - they are two different languages which run in two entirely different environments - and usually at different points in time on different physical machines. Hence why they communicate using a protocol such as HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

You can send http requst because PHP is a server side language, and JavaScript is a client-side language. JavaScript runs in the browser, while PHP runs on the server.

Create a script like this to send response in json

```
class TestClass {
    public function TestFunction() {
        return "TESTING";
    }
}

$testClass = new TestClass();

if (isset($_GET['action']) && $_GET['action'] === 'callTestFunction') {
    $result = $testClass->TestFunction();
    echo json_encode(["result" => $result]);
}
```

In html file,

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'TestClass.php?action=callTestFunction',
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data.result); // Output--"TESTING"
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, error) {
                console.error("Error:", error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

and Ok make sure to add this above the script in html

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
```